# XAMPP環境でReactを使いたい

Tags: reactjs, xampp

現在自分のローカルにXAMPPをインストールしており、C:\xampp\htdocs 配下にあるファイルがブラウザ上でhttp://localhost/　のURLで見れる状況です。
それとは別に　ローカルで　Create React App を使って、Reactが使える環境が用意できました。（npm startを実行するとブラウザ上でhttp://localhost:3000となる環境のことです。）

私がやりたいのは、ローカルで作成したReactを、XAMPP上で動かすことです。調べてみましたが初心者ですので何がうまくいかないのかわかりません。

どなたかわかる方、教えていただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: この辺の記事がそれらを扱っているようです。[How to deploy a React App on Apache web server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42461279/9014308), [React,js on Apache server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39045747/9014308), [create-react-app build deploy on LAMP/XAMPP/WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48183494/9014308), [Create Simple ReactJs Application and Host in XAMPP](https://medium.com/@nutanbhogendrasharma/create-simple-reactjs-application-and-host-in-xampp-4dae8e466c50)

Comment: kunifさん、ありがとうございます。実はリンク先のページ拝見したのですが、どれもうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: まあ事例や情報を示している記事やサイトを探して、その通りやってみたり結果の違いを考察したり等を地道にやるしかないでしょうね。何処か何方か経験があって教えてくれる人が見つかれば良いのでしょうが。[Unable to deploy React project using XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62103419/9014308), [Deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)